# Are neurodegenerative diseases such as dementia inevitable?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, physiology

For the sake of this question, let's imagine a person who lives to 200, would it be at all possible for them not to get dementia? Is it an inevitable disease as we get older or can it be avoided?

Comment: I won't think it becomes "inevitable" at 200...but yes, chances do increase, just like cancer

Comment: I think this is a great question but at this point it isn't really answerable without being substantially opinion-based.

Comment: To my knowledge the oldest verified human age is below 123 years (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oldest_people). To reach 200, revolutionary achievements are necessary. There is no telling, how these might change the probability of dementia occurring. I am afraid, any answer  is bound to be highly speculative.

Comment: While the chances do increase, the majority of people who make it past 100 don't suffer from dementia.

Comment: @jamesqf - There's a huge difference between 100 and 200. Also, the 'majority' is small, and gets smaller every half-decade. [Rates (of dementia) increased exponentially with age from 12.7% per year in the 90–94-year age group, to 21.2% per year in the 95–99-year age group, to 40.7% per year in the 100+-year age group.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3385995/). However, the answer is unknown and POB.

Comment: One of the best questions I have seen in a long time. It is very central in gerontolical research. I would argue that dementia would occur at somepoint, simply because more and more cells would be approaching the hayflick limit, leading to the inevitable loss of neurons at some stage.